Problems sending 3 alerts at once to pineconnector
I´m trying to use tradingview pinescript for algotrading, and I use pineconnector to connect with my Metatrader account.
I pretend to send 3 alerts at once, one per each partial TP for a given entry condition this way:
            alert_string = pc_entry_alertPips("buy", pc_slpips, math.round(pc_tppips), 
                    pc_bePips, pc_bePipsOffset)
            alert(alert_string, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
                        
            alert_string2 = pc_entry_alertPips("buy", pc_slpips, math.round(pc_tppips/3), 
                    pc_bePips, pc_bePipsOffset)
            alert(alert_string2, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
            
            alert_string3 = pc_entry_alertPips("buy", pc_slpips, math.round(pc_tppips*2/3), 
                    pc_bePips, pc_bePipsOffset)
            alert(alert_string3, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

Most of the times Metatrader account receives all the alerts, but sometimes only one or two of them.
Do you know of any workaround about this?

You can try Trading Router, it can send multiple messages at the same time.

Do you think their service is better being cheaper?. With Pineconnector I have problems everyday with alerts that don´t reach the webhook server.

Yes, I have used their service more than one year. It is stable and reliable. And the price is cheaper.

Syntaxis is very similar, thank you, i´ll try
